# Ubuntu GUI doesn't appear after lid is opened from suspend

Tags: nvidia, suspend, screen, 23.04, lid

I have tried all the possible tricks/suggestions that appear on Google but still unable to solve this issue.

I have a HP Victus laptop with Nvidia RTX 3050 Ti GPU. The same problem happened on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS so I upgraded to 23.04 in the hope that the problem might disappear but no luck.

I have disabled secure boot. Have changed the logind.conf settings to support suspend. But the problem is not suspend. But the GUI doesn't become alive when I open the lid. I can see screen blinking but nothing happens. Ultimately I have to do a forced shutdown.

Comment: Can you setup ssh and login via ssh during "blank screen" and check the log? (Add relevant info to the question)

Comment: Thanks @Marco for your response. I haven't tried this. I have been primarily a Windows person all my life and haven't used ssh and other Linux utilities a lot. But will do it and post it here. Thanks a lot.